# asp.net master wont use stylesheet

Tags: asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2010

I have started a new website with visual studio, and it gave me initial code to work with, I made changes to the master file and its cs aswell as the stylesheet. But the problem is the changes I made (making new tags) arent using the stylesheet. Most of the code below is defaulted with a few changes made by me. When I debug the code it creates a localhost website that still uses the default stylesheet, but will not use my own (under Log in) Please Help, Ive been trying to fix it all day :(

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>


<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div class="login">
            <div class="container">
               <!-- Hello header -->
               <div class="header">
                   <h1 class="site-name">
                   <img src="head.jpg" alt="header" />
                   <span>hello world</span></h1>
                </div>

                <!-- end header -->


                 <!--Hello Content -->
                <div class="content">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Height="21px" 
                            style="margin-left: 2px" Width="133px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br /><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Height="19px" 
                            style="margin-left: 4px" Width="133px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="button">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" 
                                Width="57px" Height="21px"/>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -99;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Login Box */
div.login
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
}

div.container
{
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #818181;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

div.header
{
    text-align:center;
}

div.site-name
{
    position: relative;
}
div.site-name span 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%
}
div.content 
{
    margin-left: 40px;
}

div.button
{
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: the css after the html is posted from the Styles/Site.css?

Comment: What do you mean your own stylesheet under your login? Have you created a new CSS file or have you modified Site.css?

Comment: Hi there, it's really hard to tell from what you've posted which styles you modified and which ones aren't working the way you expected.  Could you identify exactly which controls (by their ID) and which styles (by their style name) you want us to check out?  Thanks!

Comment: FYI for others reading this question, she appears to be using the VS2010 New ASP.NET Website template and the included Site.css file, with modifications.

Comment: I couldnt make them separate on stackoverflow for some reason it put them undersame code, they are different files. The problem is solved now thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you placed the style sheet in a protected folder, then it will not work. Put it on a folder without security restrictions.

Comment: Thank you that helped :) Cant believe it was something soo silly, I would have never figured it out myself...

Comment: Wow, how the heck did you guess that would be the problem?  If VS2010 creates the subfolder when the website is started, wouldn't it inherit permissions from its parent?

Comment: See, I still don't understand what she meant by that.  I have the same problem with my wife all the time!  gj :)

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget CTRL+R in internet explorer and CTRL+shift+R in firefox. CSS- and Javascript-files gets cached by the browser.